# Flutter on-screen keyboard not showing characters

Tags: flutter

As of recently I started receiving a broken on-screen keyboard when running (or debugging) my Flutter app.

See the attached screenshot from running a form validation demo from https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/validation.
The keyboard actually accepts keypresses. Wierd thing is that switching to uppercase makes the keyboard show the (uppercase) characters. Should I uninstall/install the stack again or are some other measures appropriate?

```
PS C:\Users\Pavel\testform> flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.20.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.1016], locale et-EE)
    • Flutter version 1.20.3 at c:\flutter
    • Framework revision 216dee60c0 (8 days ago), 2020-09-01 12:24:47 -0700
    • Engine revision d1bc06f032
    • Dart version 2.9.2

 
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\Pavel\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.3
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 47.1.2
    • Dart plugin version 193.7361
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[√] VS Code (version 1.48.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\Pavel\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.14.1

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 10 (API 29) (emulator)

• No issues found!
```

[image: Screenshot of running flutter app showing a keyboard with shift key but without characters]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to android studio -> avd manager -> your emulator -> wipe data and try again. If not resolved, delete the emulator and create a new one.

Comment: I"m using VS Code, not Android Studio. But I followed your recommendation and created a new Flutter emulator which seems to resolve the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Try to cold-boot the emulator. This works for me!